# How to paste the string so that I can call the variables?

Tags: r, for-loop, paste

I have a handful of objects with the format: `test.name`
My objective is to write a loop to plot 10 ablines with the vectors `test.name$scores` against the variable `money` with the corresponding colors on a preceding plot.

My thought is:

```
#set up a df for the name and color
df <- data.frame(
  c('Amy','Peter','Jerry','Max','Angela','Mike','Kenny','Boris','Jack','Danial'),
  color = c(1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))

plot(my_plot)    

#write a for-loop to iterate the name and the color in the abline function
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
  abline(lm(________~money), col=d[i,2],lwd=2)
}
```

The problem is how to fill in ________? I need to paste 'test.'+d[i,1]+'$scores'. But using `paste0` results in a string but not variables I call for.

Comment: Try using `as.formula`

Comment: Your question is not reproducible: your data's first column name is `X1` which you never use, you never define `money` or `d`, and never use `df`. Please try your own code in a fresh R session (nothing predefined) before finalizing questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval() to execute a String as if it was R-Code. For example:

```
a = 5
b = "+"
c = '7'

ex = c(a,b,c, "-3")
ex = paste(ex, sep="", collapse = '') # Make sure there are no separators or quotation marks
ex #"5+7-3"
temp = eval(parse(text = ex))
temp #9
```

I dont know your particular problem but this could maybe help you:

```
# I dont know what your values are...
i = 1
d = matrix(c("someValue",2,3,4,5,6), ncol = 2)

ex = c("abline(lm(", d[i,1], "$scores", "~money), col=d[i,2],lwd=2)")
ex = paste(ex, sep="", collapse = '')
ex # "abline(lm(someValue$scores~money), col=d[i,2],lwd=2)"
eval(parse(text = ex))
```

eval(parse(text = ex)) would try to run the String "ex" as if it was R-Code. You need to check your formatting tho.

Comment: The use of `eval(parse(text=..))` is such a risky (and not-cheap) method that it should only be used as a last resort. There are plenty of other ways to deal with this, starting with NadPat's suggested use of `as.formula`.